# How to replace cp command with wget?

Tags: command-line, bash, docker, wget, cp

I am very newbie to linux and its commands. What I want is use `cp` command instead of `wget` to request from browser. Because I'm using docker and the [mongo site](https://mongodb.org/) filtered our country's IP. I have downloaded the file on my local system and want to copy it to the specific path. I want the same functionality with `wget` command.

Here is my import-data.sh file:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget
wget -O /tmp/zips.json "http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json"
mongoimport --db=test --collection=zips /tmp/zips.json
```

As I mentioned, the zips.json file have been downloaded on the local (`./zips.json`) and don't know how to replace it with cp or any other command to work correctly.

Comment: @user68186 it's in the current directory: `./zips.json`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a Dockerfile RUN directive that you posted.  If you are building docker images and have a file local to your machine that needs to be copied into the docker image, then you need to add the Dockerfile COPY directive:

```
COPY <src file> <dest>
```

For you, that would be

```
COPY zips.json /tmp/zips.json
```

Which would copy the zips.json from your Host file system into the container image at the /tmp/zips.json location.

The COPY directive must be added before the RUN directive. You also need to remove the wget portion from the run directive.

Comment: This when building, or attach a local folder as volume `docker run -v ./tmp:/tmp ...` for directly running.

Comment: Question upvoted from -1 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

## Why copy to `/tmp/` at all?

---

As you have downloaded the file in the current folder, you don't need the first two lines of `import-data.sh`. I would suggest comment out the first two lines and modify the last line to point to the current folder:

```
#apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget
#wget -O /tmp/zips.json "http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json"
mongoimport --db=test --collection=zips ./zips.json
```

Note the `#` (comment sign) in the begining of the first two lines and the location of the downloaded file `zips.json` in the current folder.

Hope this helps